# Is it off-topic to ask about how to find freelance UX jobs?

Tags: discussion

**TL;DR**

Is it on topic to ask about how to find freelance UX gigs?

**Background**

I haven't been in the UX world long (since I graduated, roughly 9 months ago) and my title at my job is "UI/UX Developer". Despite working on various projects for work, my company technically owns everything, so none of it can go into my portfolio which leaves me no work showing what UI/UX related work I have done.

I'm looking to build a more UX relevant portfolio and have been looking for opportunities on sites like [Elance](https://www.elance.com/), but I always get beat out by a company or someone with more portfolio pieces to show. Other than that, I don't know really know where to go.

Is this an appropriate question to ask on [UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com) or is it too off-topic?

Comment: Off topic, but cool of you to ask here on meta! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where there is likely to be dissension among users, as it comes down to what you believe the site should be used for.

- Is it strictly a UX question? No
- Would it be helpful for UX practitioners? Likely, yes.

I would like the site to be used more for the latter question, but my understanding of the guidelines of the site are more in lines with the former, so I would have to close a question like this.

However, you're free to ask this in Chat.

I'd be happy to revise my understanding of the site guidelines, but I would first have to wait for feedback from the other mods.

Comment: What about putting it in the community wiki? Is that a viable option? I think it's something that would be good for folks to know and collect resources, but not necessarily an 'answerable question', you know?

Comment: @BDD that isn't really a UX question.  It's a jobs question where the job happens to be UX.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a Meta question either. Meta posts should be *exclusively* for questions relating to this stackexchange site, the software that powers it, and the rules of posting. So asking if something is suitable to post on the site is a meta question, but asking about finding jobs isn't.

Comment: @JonW You're right.  I've removed the invite to ask in Meta